# Returning arbitraty length array of structs in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

In a contract i'm trying to implement some kind of recursivity of struct.

I have a map of wallets addresses that correspond to structs of type Ticket.

```
struct Ticket {
        uint256 ticketId;
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
    }
mapping (address => Ticket) tickets;
```

my problem with this solution is that i don't know how to return every ticket that have have a same address.

```
function setTicket(address _address, string memory _firstname, string memory _lastname) public returns(uint256){
        
        uint256 ticketNewId = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty)));
        Ticket storage ticket = tickets[_address];
        ticket.firstname = _firstname;
        ticket.lastname = _lastname;
        ticket.ticketId = ticketNewId;
        ticketaccts.push(_address);
        return ticketNewId;
    }
    
    function getTickets() view public returns(address[] memory){
        return ticketaccts;
    }
    
    function getTicket(address _address) view public returns (Ticket memory){
        return (tickets[_address]);
    }
```

here getTicket() return the last ticket with the _address given.
but what i want is return all the ticket with the same _address
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end the solution i choose is the following:

```
function getTicketByAddress(address _address) public view returns (Ticket[] memory){ 
        Ticket[] memory ticketByAddress = new Ticket[](tickets[_address].length);

        uint numberOfTicket = 0;

        for(uint i = 0; i < tickets[_address].length;  i++) {
            ticketByAddress[numberOfTicket] = tickets[_address][i];
            numberOfTicket++;
        }

        return ticketByAddress; //don't work well in remix!
    }
```

exemple of usage in a refund function:

```
function makeRefund(uint256 _ticketId ) public returns(Ticket memory) {
        Ticket[] memory ticketByAddress = new Ticket[](tickets[msg.sender].length);
        Ticket memory refundTicket;

        uint numberOfTicket = 0;

        for(uint i = 0; i < tickets[msg.sender].length;  i++) {
            ticketByAddress[numberOfTicket] = tickets[msg.sender][i];
            numberOfTicket++;
        }
        ticketByAddress[_ticketId].refunded = true;
        refundTicket = ticketByAddress[_ticketId];
        
        if(refundTicket.categorie == 1){
            uint256 time = (dateEvent - refundTicket.date)/86400;
            require(time >= 1, "It is too late for a refund!");
            msg.sender.transfer(ticketPrice);
            
            maxTickets++;
            totalTicket++;
        }

        return refundTicket;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an old fashioned solution to provide to read calls

- One to get the number of tickets `getTicketCount(address)`
- One to get nth ticket `getTicket(address, n)`